# Aftermarket options for adjusting Giant Aero Bars angle

Tags: parts, bike-fit, riding-position, aero-bars

I have this Giant 2016 Trinity Pro that I'm trying to make some adjustments to. Currently the stock aero bars stick almost straight out and I'm not super happy with that position. I've really liked the look of the "mantis" position where the front end of the aero bars are elevated closer to the rider's face. However, I haven't found any options for being able to adjust this. Are there any spacers/angle mounts that I can use to adjust these angles?

[image: Aero Bars]

Answer (score 3):

We try to avoid specific product recommendations here. That said, this is a niche problem and there aren't a lot of solutions.

Your problem here is that most stock aerobars are designed to clamp onto a round 31.8-mm diameter section of handlebar. Not only do you not have round bars, it looks like the bar/stem interface isn't round. So you would need to swap your stem, base bars, and aero bars to effect this change.

The alternative is to find someone making adapters or aerobars that will work with your existing mounts. You might try contacting Giant directly to see if they have angled adapters. The other option that I know of is [Aerocoach](https://www.aero-coach.co.uk/store/Aerobar-components-c51437190), which makes very high-end aerobars with a variety of fittings. This could wind up being more expensive than the first option.

Comment: I was eyeballing the aerocoach but I'm not keen on paying $100 for a block of metal that I could cut on a CNC machine for $20. I'll try contacting giant and see what they say, or if they can provide measurements for what the adapter would need to be.

Comment: @blackbrandt If you can CNC cut something yourself, why not simply try? The interfaces seem to have reasonably flat contact surfaces, so just making an aluminum wedge with the appropriate holes-with-threads should be sufficient until you find the angle you're looking for. Then refine your wedge to look nice.

Comment: I'm planning on 3D printing a few for my bike fitting to play with the angles, once I find the angle I like then I'll send it off to get CNC cut.

Answer (score 3):

Differently shaped spacers is the likely solution I also came across after a brief Google search. Now, it appears that Aerocoach is not the only purveyor of such spacers. These guys on AliExpress sell a spacer branded to Fouriers that looks like it may fit the Trinity - although I'm not sure of their model history, so these specific ones may or may not fit. The spacers are a lot cheaper than Aerocoach.

What might you be giving up for the extra money? Most likely material quality and manufacturing tolerances. Because these spacers aren't structural elements, I am guessing that material may not be that important. Tolerances may affect if the spacers fit precisely. If the spacers fit loosely, you might not be able to properly tighten them down. It's impossible to say if this will happen without getting them and fitting them.

If you get no satisfaction here, then you may wish to seek out a more triathlon or TT-oriented site. Slowtwitch.com is one such forum, and there's actually a thread [here](https://forum.slowtwitch.com/forum/Slowtwitch_Forums_C1/Triathlon_Forum_F1/Official_Giant_Trinity_Advanced_Owners_Thread_P6247506-17/?t=lgrvnwabqaxqjpg). Another option is to find an LBS that has experienced with tri/TT bikes - as you now know, these are rather specialist bikes that involve some unique equipment, and not all stores may be able to assist you well.